# How to seed pivot table that has field?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I have a number in pivot table and I don't know how I can set the value in number.

The task of number filed in pivot table : Specifies the order of the video in the playlist

---

videos

- title
- description
- videoUrl

---

playlists

- title
- description

---

playlist_videos

- playlist_id
- video_id
- number

---

```
User::factory()->count(5)
        ->has(Playlist::factory()->count(3)
            ->has(Video::factory()->count(10)
                ->state(function (array $attributes, Playlist $playlist) {
                    $number = 1;
                    $arr = ['user_id' => $playlist->user_id];
                    $playlist->videos()->sync(['number' => $number]);
                    $number = $number + 1;
                    return $arr;
                })))
                ->create();
```

---

error :

In `Connection.php` line 692:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'number' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `playlist_videos` (`playlist_id`, `video_id`) values (11, Qui et magni itaque.))

In `Connection.php` line 485:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'number' doesn't have a default value

Comment: [hasAttached](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#pivot-table-attributes), prehaps that.

Comment: This is good but I want the field of number increment after each attach

Comment: `->hasAttached(Video::factory()->count(10), fn () => ['number' => ++$i])`